# How do I correct the case statement in sql?

Tags: sql, oracle

```
CASE
WHEN ORDER_MODE='online' then ORDER_TOTAL= SUM(ORDER_TOTAL*0.20)
WHEN ORDER_STATUS='1'THEN ORDER_TOTAL= SUM(ORDER_TOTAL*0.10)
```

a CASE statement to return ORDER_TOTAL +
20% when the ORDER_MODE is ‘online’
and ORDER_TOTAL + 10% when the ORDER_STATUS is
1.

Answer (score 1):

You would use it like this
in a select statement

```
SUM(CASE
WHEN ORDER_MODE='online' then  ORDER_TOTAL*0.20
WHEN ORDER_STATUS='1'THEN ORDER_TOTAL*0.10
END) as ORDER_TOTAL
```